# Vectorization using accumarray

Tags: matlab, vectorization, accumulate, accumarray

I want to project the texture of 3D surface (`CylCoors` *300000x3*) into a 2D plane (`Image` 380x360). For doing so I take every unique value in Z (`UniqueZ=unique(CylCoors(:,3))`) and and Theta (`UniqueTheta=unique(CylCoors(:,1))`) and project all the texture values (`PointValues` *300000x1*) where both meet like this:

```
Image=zeros(max(UniqueH),max(UniqueTheta)); %380x360

tic

HMat=bsxfun(@eq,CylCoors(:,3),UniqueH');  % 300000x380
ThetaMat=bsxfun(@eq,CylCoors(:,1),UniqueTheta'); %300000x360


for ii=1:length(UniqueH)          % Sloooow and not nice :(
    for jj=1:length(UniqueTheta)

        Image(ii,jj)=sum(PointValues.*...
            HMat(:,ii).*ThetaMat(:,jj))/...
            sum(HMat(:,ii).*ThetaMat(:,jj));

    end
end

toc
```

Here's an example with trimmed variables:

```
CylCoorsSample = [263.0000  184.2586   10.0000    
                  264.0000  183.0417   10.0000    
                  264.0000  182.1572   10.0000    
                  82.0000   157.4746   11.0000    
                  80.0000   158.2348   11.0000    
                  86.0000   157.3507   11.0000    
                  84.0000   157.7633   11.0000]   

PointValuesSample = [0.4745
                     0.5098
                     0.5020
                     0.4784
                     0.4510
                     0.4431
                     0.5804]


UniqueTheta = [80              
               82              
               84
               86
               263
               264]

UniqueH =[10
          11]

ThetaMat =                             HMat =   

 0     0     0     0     1     0       1   0
 0     0     0     0     0     1       1   0
 0     0     0     0     0     1       1   0
 0     1     0     0     0     0       0   1
 1     0     0     0     0     0       0   1
 0     0     0     1     0     0       0   1
 0     0     1     0     0     0       0   1 

Image =        % size: length(UniqueH)xlength(UniqueTheta)

   NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN    0.4745    0.5059
0.4510    0.4784    0.5804    0.4431       NaN       NaN
```

Is there a way to vectorize the `for` loops using `accumarray`? Something tells me this is the case, but I find the multidimensional sub indexing for this function quite confusing.

Any other vectorization solutions (using smart combinations of `reshape`,`bsxfun`, and `sum` I assume) are also welcome, but I would really like to understand this use of `accumarray` a bit better.

Comment: Can you add a small sample input and output?

Comment: No I mean make a *small* sample with the input matrix in simplified numbers and how the numbers are altered just to demonstrate your process

Comment: Got you now! I was wondering how my last edit was going to help much :D

Comment: Are `UniqueTheta` and `UniqueH` supposed to be the element coordinates of where each point in `PointValuesSample` (or the average if  more than one point is indexed) are supposed to lie on your final output `Image`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it does. The surface would be ideally just one value, but the segmentation and rounding sometimes produces many points with the same coordinates Theta and Z that only differ in Radius coordinate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
CylCoorsSample = [263.0000  184.2586   10.0000    
                  264.0000  183.0417   10.0000    
                  264.0000  182.1572   10.0000    
                  82.0000   157.4746   11.0000    
                  80.0000   158.2348   11.0000    
                  86.0000   157.3507   11.0000    
                  84.0000   157.7633   11.0000]   

PointValuesSample = [0.4745
                     0.5098
                     0.5020
                     0.4784
                     0.4510
                     0.4431
                     0.5804]
```

You can use `accumarray` as follows (using the third output of `unique` to generate the required `subs` input):

```
[UniqueTheta, ~, subsTheta]=unique(CylCoorsSample(:,1))
[UniqueH,~,subsH]=unique(CylCoorsSample(:,3))
sz = [numel(UniqueH), numel(UniqueTheta)]

Image = accumarray([subsH, subsTheta], PointValuesSample, sz, @mean, NaN)
```

Comment: Works perfectly, but I will have to sit down a while and dissect accumarray() and all it's parameters to really understand it Thank you!

Comment: subs is a list of row vectors of positions in the output matrix. So if row one of subs is `[1 1]` then it means put row 1 of `val` in position `[1 1]` of the output. However if there are many rows of subs with that same value (i.e. `[1 1]` in my example), then put all corresponding `val` values in that position but aggregate them using the `fun` function handle (in my case `@mean` so average them).

Comment: Now that is exactly what I had not understood yet! It's all clear now, thanks again for a great answer.